# Is there any way to create a react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I've been trying to create a react-redux file but I've been getting some error in that.
The problem I am getting is this.
C:\Users\Maaz Parkar\Desktop\REDUX LOGIN>npx create-react-app my-app --template redux
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

C:\Users\Maaz Parkar\Desktop\REDUX LOGIN> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 250ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: If you read the link you posted, it explains everything you need to do.

Comment: I did but It is not helping  me out

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`

Comment: @MaazParkar did you try uninstalling the globally installed `npx` version ? `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing it correctly.

First make sure npm and node are up to date and then open the Command Prompt and write:

```
npx create-react-app <name>
```

`<name>` is the name of your app.

After than is done `cd` into the folder and run

```
npm i redux react-redux reduxjs/toolkit
```

or with yarn:

```
yarn add redux react-redux reduxjs/toolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library

1. `npm i -g create-react-redux-app-structure` or `yarn add global create-react-redux-app-structure`
2. `create-react-redux-app-structure my-app`
3. `cd my-app`

It will create more structured project easily.